# mySQL GROUP_CONCAT And Calculation Process

Tags: sql, mysql

I record the total sales numbers every day to calculate the daily sales increase of the products.

What I want to do is;

Finding records between 2 dates and getting the sales difference between them.

I can combine sales numbers with GROUP_CONCAT, but this is not enough. I need to find the difference and sort them accordingly.

| product_id | date | total_sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-10-06 | 5 |
| 1 | 2023-10-07 | 12 |
| 2 | 2023-10-06 | 1 |
| 2 | 2023-10-07 | 5 |

The query I tried but was not sufficient.

```sql
SELECT product_id,GROUP_CONCAT(total_sales SEPARATOR '-') as sales 
FROM product_daily 
WHERE (date='2023-10-06' or date='2023-10-07')  
group by product_id
```

**I need to get an output like the following.**

| product_id | sales_difference |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 7 |
| 2 | 4 |

Comment: Self join or lag window functuon is what ypu need, not group concat.

Comment: @Shadow If you have a query suggestion for a solution, I would be happy if you answer it.

Answer (score 1):

You expect two values per group. You want to subtract the lower one from the higher one:

```
SELECT product_id, MAX(total_sales) - MIN(total_sales) AS sales_difference 
FROM product_daily 
WHERE date IN (DATE '2023-10-06', DATE '2023-10-07')
GROUP BY product_id
ORDER BY sales_difference DESC;
```

**UPDATE:** In the comments below, Shadow assumes that there can be decreases instead of increases and that you'd rather want to subtract the first day's amount from the second's. I don't know, if that is the case or not. Is the total_sales the sales for that one day or for all days until that day? It sounds like the latter, so total_sales would increase with each day and the difference would be the day's separate sales. But well, if total_sales is a single day's sale and you want to consider the date in the subtraction, you can use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT
  product_id,
  MAX(CASE WHEN date = DATE '2023-10-07' THEN total_sales END) - 
  MIN(CASE WHEN date = DATE '2023-10-06' THEN total_sales END)
    AS sales_difference 
FROM product_daily 
WHERE date IN (DATE '2023-10-06', DATE '2023-10-07')
GROUP BY product_id
ORDER BY sales_difference DESC;
```

Well, in that case it doesn't matter, whether to use `MIN` and `MAX`, as you expect just one value per day.

Comment: This solution assumes that the sale will increase over time, which may not be true.

Comment: @Shadow: No it doesn't. It asssumes that the OP wants to subtract the lower value from the greater one. In other words: to get the absolute diffference. There is nothing in the request to indicate they want it otherwise, Their `GROUP_CONCAT` is even oblivious to any order. But yes, they may want one thing or the other. The request is not clear about this.

Comment: "I record the total sales numbers every day to calculate the daily sales increase of the products" - this makes sense from a business point of view. Your query does not.

Comment: @Shadow: Thank you. You may be right. We cannot know for certain, so I've updated my answer with an explantion and a solution for this other scenario.